# Javascript How to open a new tab?

Tags: javascript, getjson

I've created a function using `getJson` that allows a user to search for a specific user and display all their data.

```html
 <body>

     <input id="search" type="text">
     <button>Search</button>
     <div id="results"></div>

     <script>
         $('button').on('click', function() {
             var user = $('#search').val();
             $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/" + user)
                 .done(function(user) {
                     var br = "<br>";
                     var p = $("<p id='users'></p>");
                     var name = "Username: " + user.login + br;
                     var pic = "Avatar Picture:" + br + "<img src='" + user.avatar_url + "'/>" + br;
                     var homeURl = "Homepage URL: " + "<a href='" + user.html_url + "'>" + user.html_url + "</a>" + br;
                     var location = "Location: " + "Null" + br;
                     var admin = "Admin: " + user.site_admin;
                     p.append("<p>" + name + pic + homeURl + location + admin + "</p>");

                     $("#results").empty().append(p);
                 })
                 .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                     console.log("Error: " + jqXHR.status);
                 })
                 .always(function() {
                     console.log("Random Users Request finished");
                 });
         });
     </script>
 </body>
```

For example if the user types in "mojombo" then all the information relevant to the user "mojombo" is displayed.

I am currently wishing to modify this function such this data is accessed through clicking on the user name rather than searching. For example, if the user name "mojombo" is displayed and the user clicks the name then a new tab should open displaying all the information relevant to the user mojombo.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Answer updated with snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Based on your question specifically. You just need to add the target attribute to the a tag you already have.

```
 var homeURl = "Homepage URL: " + "<a href='" + user.html_url + "' target='_blank'>" + user.html_url + "</a>" + br;
```

Here's a snippet.

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
        var user = $('#search').val();
        $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/" + user)
          .done(function (user) {
            var br = "<br>";
            var p = $("<p id='users'></p>");
            var name = "Username: " + user.login + br;
            var pic = "Avatar Picture:" + br + "<img src='" + user.avatar_url + "'/>" + br;
            var homeURl = "Homepage URL: " + "<a href='" + user.html_url + "' target='_blank'>" + user.html_url + "</a>" + br;
            var location = "Location: " + "Null" + br;
            var admin = "Admin: " + user.site_admin;
            p.append("<p>" + name + pic + homeURl + location + admin + "</p>");

            $("#results").empty().append(p);
          })
          .fail(function (jqXHR) {
            console.log("Error: " + jqXHR.status);
          })
          .always(function () {
            console.log("Random Users Request finished");
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text">
    <button>Search</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Lol, i thought he was asking to open a new tab on the browser

Comment: I believe this is correct or close to it, however when I implement it no users appear when I search

Comment: Ah you just need to change the a tag for the hompageUrl

 var homeURl = "Homepage URL: " + "<a href='" + user.html_url + "' target='_blank'>" + user.html_url + "</a>" + br;

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    window.open($(e.currentTarget).attr('href'));
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand your question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input id="search" type="text">
    <button>Search</button>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script>
        const html = $("<html></html>");
        $('button').on('click', function() {
            var user = $('#search').val();
            $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/" + user)
                .done(function(user) {
                    var br = "<br>";
                    var p = $("<p id='users'></p>");
                    var name = "Username: " + user.login + br;
                    var pic = "Avatar Picture:" + br + "<img src='" + user.avatar_url + "'/>" + br;
                    var homeURl = "Homepage URL: " + "<a href='" + user.html_url + "'>" + user.html_url + "</a>" + br;
                    var location = "Location: " + "Null" + br;
                    var admin = "Admin: " + user.site_admin;
                    p.append("<p>" + name + pic + homeURl + location + admin + "</p>");
                    html.append($('<body>').append(p));
                    var w = window.open("");
                    w.document.write(html.html())
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                    console.log("Error: " + jqXHR.status);
                })
                .always(function() {
                    console.log("Random Users Request finished");
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its close, sorry if my question isn't clear haha, But its more when the user searches for someone and that data is displayed, they can then click on the username to view more information on that user

Comment: @dylzee got the answer for you then :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a page for viewing the detailed information and passing data to the page through GET.

```
window.open('example.com/detail?avatarUrl=' + user.avatar_url + "&htmlUrl=" + user.html_url)
```

Comment: This way, he would need to have a server set up to parse that information from the request query and then render the information